# Inline-block and margin: auto not working for input

Tags: html, css

I am new to CSS. I want my textbox (input) to be center aligned, also, I want to set a specific height to it. I want it to be responsive, so I am using % instead of px. It (%) seems to be working for width, but not for the height. For height, only px values are working. Also, I assigned my input's display property to be `inline-block` and `margin 0 auto`, but it is not working. Where am I going wrong??

Here's the code:

```
input {
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 20%;
}
```

Here's a code sample.

```css
input {
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 20%;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

Comment: You have to be need parents div width property and then nested div or tag width with `display: block` and `margin: 0 auto`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `%` for height you will have to add some helper CSS first. Like the following:

```
html,body{
  height:100%;
}
```

and for making the `<input>` *centre* use

```
margin: 0 auto;
display: block;
```

A working sample for you:

```css
input {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  height: 20%;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

There is an easy another way if you are Interested you can go with [`vh`](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/)*[Viewport-height]*,
for this method, there is no need to use any other helping CSS to use, so the choice is yours..

A working sample for this method:

```css
input {
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    height: 20vh;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

Hope this was helpfull.

Answer (score 1):

In CSS, some, if not most, properties of an element depends on its parent's properties.

So, to make `height: 20%` work, you need to set a height for the `input`'s parent. In the example below, `body` is the parent of `input`.

To center-align an element using `margin: 0 auto`, the element must have `display: block`.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;      /* Set a parent height */
}
input {
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;  /* Use display: block; */
    height: 20%;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pritam1605/n2mkvwq5/ why is this not working then??

Comment: @PritamBohra because of the typo in the html. The class of `div` in html is written as `input-wraper` while in CSS it is written `input-wrapper`.

Answer (score 0):

Set this style to `input` tag.

```css
input {
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    height: 20vh;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give display:block for aligned center to input and display:inline-block is already apply here  and give height to body,html for applying height to input

```css
html,body{
  height:100%;
}
input {
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    height: 20%;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you will not work with `flex` then `display:block;` and `width` is important for centering elements.

```css
div {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

input{
  display:block;
  width: 70%;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size:18px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `display: inline-block;` to `display: block;` and `height: 20%;` to `height: 20vh;`

```css
input {
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    height: 20vh;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

**UPDATE**

Only change `display: inline-block;` to `display: flex;`

```css
input {
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    height: 20%;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
```